# Issue displaying data from aspnetusers table in published blazor wasm app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I have blazor wasm app written in net 5
Application deployed in azure on windows VM with mssql database
Locally running app with database connection string in azure show all data from database correctly
Published application does not show data associated with identityUser

```
 public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    // relationship
    public Nationality Nationality { get; set; }

}
```

data from fields DisplayName, Image shows correctly but other fields does not shown
if I do [api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MApea.jpg) to my controller I see all fields in json format

```
 public UserController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }


    [HttpGet("all")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AppUser[]>> All() =>
        await _userManager.Users.ToArrayAsync();
```

and this is my [view in blazor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cawyd.jpg)

```
    <MudTable Items="@appUsers" Hover="true" Class="my-5">
    <RowTemplate>
    <MudTd> 
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="@context.Image" style="min-height:100px;height:100px;" />
    </MudTd>
    <MudTd>@context.DisplayName</MudTd>
    <MudTd>@context.UserName</MudTd>
    <MudTd>@context.Email</MudTd>       
    </RowTemplate>
   </MudTable>
   @code {
         private List<AppUser> appUsers = new List<AppUser>();

         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
            appUsers = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<AppUser>>("api/user/all");
          }
   }
```

Startup.cs

```
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(o => o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
 public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Nationality> Nationalities { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [api call image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MApea.jpg) Nationality is null. I adjust the API method to [eager load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) `Nationality`.

```cs
await _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Nationality).ToArrayAsync();
```

I would also temporarily enable [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) to make sure the queries are executing as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution that helped me was to create a POCO class and wrap a selection from the database into it